# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level_

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
range_studio_minuti_gennaio = 44640

for a in range(range_studio_minuti_gennaio):
    x_a=int(a % 1440)
    ora_genn = int(x_a/60)
    min_genn= int(x_a%60)

    for b in range(31):
        giorno_genn = b


    anno = 2014
    mese_genn = 1

   data = "giorno_genn,mese_genn,anno"
```

and the output for data is

```
runfile('C:/Users/Stefano/Downloads/WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5/python-3.4.3.amd64/Scripts/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Stefano/Downloads/WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5/python-3.4.3.amd64/Scripts')
  File "C:/Users/Stefano/Downloads/WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5/python-3.4.3.amd64/Scripts/untitled0.py", line 32
    data = "giorno_genn,mese_genn,anno"
                                   ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: By reading the error message?

Comment: Error message says everything you need to know

Comment: The last code line is not well indent. You have to add an space.

Answer (score -1):

```
range_studio_minuti_gennaio = 44640

for a in range(range_studio_minuti_gennaio):
    x_a=int(a % 1440)
    ora_genn = int(x_a/60)
    min_genn= int(x_a%60)

    for b in range(31):
        giorno_genn = b

    anno = 2014
    mese_genn = 1

    data = "giorno_genn,mese_genn,anno"
```

You have to add an space before data = "giorno_genn,mese_genn,anno".

Comment: `data` could be indented or unindented, you don't know for sure

Comment: @cricket_007 you are right. But it's sure that is not well indented

Comment: Instead of answering typographical error questions you should flag them as such.